# What is physical meaning of gravitoelectromagnetic field $E$ and $B$ in gravity?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

We know that there are Maxwell-like equations in [gravitoelectromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism). But I dont know the physical meaning of $E_{g}$ and $B_{g}$. In electromagnetism, electric field $E$ is generated by charges and magnetic field $B$ is generated by moving charges. But, in gravity, basically there are no magnetic and electric fields. $E_{g}$ and $B_{g}$ are just fields analog to the  electromagnetic fields. So, what is the meaning of $E_{g}$ and $B_{g}$ in gravity?

I am currently researching gravitoelectromagnetism in teleparallel gravity, 
through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02464), but in this paper doesn't explain the physical meaning about the fields $E$ and $B$.

Answer (score 4):

The Lorentz force law for electromagnetism, $F=q(E+\tfrac{v}{c}\times B)$, includes a magnetic force proportional to velocity.  The corresponding gravitational force law (the geodesic equation in weak-field GR) has a Newtonian term $(\Gamma _{00}^{m})$ that may be called gravito-electric, and extra terms $(\Gamma _{i0}^{m}\And \Gamma _{ij}^{m})$ proportional to $v/c$ and ${{v}^{2}}/{{c}^{2}}$, which may be called gravito-magnetic.

How might these arise?  Think of a rotating but otherwise stationary star.  A test particle in orbit around it would feel slightly different forces depending on whether it moves pro- or retrograde, because the star's rotation acts much like a current loop.  This effect is much exaggerated around rotating black holes, where it is known as *frame dragging*.